# join with a table but only on certain condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to add a join but only when a certain condition is met.

Let me explain with an example.

I have these 3 tables

**Table_I**

```
I_ID    Value   Ischecked   Region  
----    -----   ---------   ------  
1       A       0           N1  
2       B       1           N1  
3       C       0           N2
```

**Table_PB**

```
PB_ID   Region  Code    
-----   ------  ----    
1       N1      A1  
2       N1      A2  
3       N1      A3  
4       N2      C1
```

**Table_D**

```
D_ID    I_ID    PB_ID   
----    ----    -----   
1       1       1   
2       1       2   
3       3       1   
4       3       4
```

**An my wanted result is this**

```
I_ID    Value   IsChecked   Region  PB_ID   Code    
----    -----   ---------   ------  -----   ----    
1       A       0           N1      1       A1  
1       A       0           N1      2       A2  
2       B       1           N1      null    A1  
2       B       1           N1      null    A2  
2       B       1           N1      null    A3  
3       C       0           N2      1       A1  
3       C       0           N2      4       C1
```

**How do I got this result ?**

Well I start with all rows from `Table_I` and join them with `Table_D` and finally with `Table_PB`
The catch is that when no row is found in `Table_D` and `IsChecked is 1` then I need an extra join on `Table_PB` that will add all rows with the same `Region` as found in `Table_I`

I hope it is clear what I mean.

**So what I got now is this**

```
declare @Table_I table (I_ID int, Value varchar(10), Ischecked bit, Region varchar(2))
insert into @Table_I values (1, 'A', 0, 'N1'), (2, 'B', 1, 'N1'), (3, 'C', 0, 'N2')

declare @Table_PB table (PB_ID int, Region varchar(2), Code varchar(2))
insert into @Table_PB values (1, 'N1', 'A1'), (2, 'N1', 'A2'), (3, 'N1', 'A3'), (4, 'N2', 'C1')

declare @Table_D table (D_ID int, I_ID int, PB_ID int)
insert into @Table_D values (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 3, 1), (4, 3, 4)

select i.I_ID, i.Value, i.IsChecked, i.Region, d.PB_ID, pb.Code
from   @Table_I i
  left outer join @Table_D d on i.I_ID = d.I_ID
  left outer join @Table_PB pb on d.PB_ID = pb.PB_ID
```

This produces this result

```
I_ID    Value   IsChecked   Region  PB_ID   Code    
----    -----   ---------   ------  -----   ----    
1       A       0           N1      1       A1  
1       A       0           N1      2       A2  
2       B       1           N1      null    null    
3       C       0           N2      1       A1  
3       C       0           N2      4       C1
```

When you compare this with my wanted result you can see the difference for the row with I_ID = 2

Can this be done and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating the logic between 2 sets with `UNION ALL`:

```
-- Records from I that exists on D
SELECT
    I.I_ID,
    I.Value,
    I.Ischecked,
    I.Region,
    D.PB_ID,
    P.Code
FROM
    @Table_I AS I
    INNER JOIN @Table_D AS D ON I.I_ID = D.I_ID
    INNER JOIN @Table_PB AS P ON D.PB_ID = P.PB_ID

UNION ALL

-- Records from I that don't exist on D and are checked
SELECT
    I.I_ID,
    I.Value,
    I.Ischecked,
    I.Region,
    PB_ID = NULL, --P.PB_ID,
    P.Code
FROM
    @Table_I AS I
    INNER JOIN @Table_PB AS P ON I.Region = P.Region
WHERE
    I.Ischecked = 1 AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'no record on D' FROM @Table_D AS D WHERE D.I_ID = I.I_ID)

ORDER BY
    1
```

Results:

```
I_ID    Value   Ischecked   Region  PB_ID   Code
1       A       0           N1      1       A1
1       A       0           N1      2       A2
2       B       1           N1      NULL    A1
2       B       1           N1      NULL    A2
2       B       1           N1      NULL    A3
3       C       0           N2      4       C1
3       C       0           N2      1       A1
```

I'm forcing a `NULL` on the 2nd set because it matches your desired outcome, but there is a `PB_ID` you can display here that comes from the `@Table_PB` table (it's commented on code).

Comment: Simple solution, I did not think of using union for this but it will work. Also I dont really need the `PB_ID` I just kept it in my example to show clear that that join did not returned any rows

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE

```
declare @Table_I table (I_ID int, Value varchar(10), Ischecked bit, Region varchar(2))
insert into @Table_I values (1, 'A', 0, 'N1'), (2, 'B', 1, 'N1'), (3, 'C', 0, 'N2')

declare @Table_PB table (PB_ID int, Region varchar(2), Code varchar(2))
insert into @Table_PB values (1, 'N1', 'A1'), (2, 'N1', 'A2'), (3, 'N1', 'A3'), (4, 'N2', 'C1')

declare @Table_D table (D_ID int, I_ID int, PB_ID int)
insert into @Table_D values (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 3, 1), (4, 3, 4)

;
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT i.I_ID, count(D.PB_ID) as CountD
    FROM @Table_I i
    LEFT JOIN @Table_D D ON i.I_ID = d.I_ID 
    GROUP BY i.I_ID
)
SELECT 
    i.I_ID, i.Value, i.IsChecked, i.Region, d.PB_ID, pb.Code
FROM CTE c
  join @Table_I i on i.I_ID = c.i_id
  left join @Table_D d on i.I_ID = d.I_ID
  left join @Table_PB pb on (d.PB_ID = pb.PB_ID) OR (c.CountD = 0 AND i.isChecked = 1 AND i.Region = pb.Region)
```

Comment: sorry, i copied it twice... is fixed now

Comment: sorry, I'm running updates on my machine and I'm unable to use SSMS i am coding on notepad